# Give structure to tweets in JSON format

Tags: php, json, twitter, tweets

I have the following code, which displays tweets in `JSON` format to an `HTML` page. I would like **to display these tweets** in a more presentable manner. Could anyone provide me with any options?

```
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth-master/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$twitteruser = "massa_jes";
$notweets = 1;

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

$resArr = json_encode($tweets); //decodes the json string to an array
var_dump($resArr);
```

Comment: You should be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve. Are you planning to embed the tweets in an HTML page? (Also, please remove the leading spaces from your code example.)

Comment: Yes, I want the tweets to be embedded in an HTML page, and I have removed the leading spaces in my question

Comment: Well, if you want HTML then I suggest you pump out HTML instead of `var_dump($resArr);`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$tweetsArr = json_decode($tweets,true); //decodes the json string to an array
foreach($tweetsArr as $tweet) {
echo $tweet['text']."<br />";
...
...
}
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to go for, however I am being given the following error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: check the count of $tweetsArr if count($tweetsArr)=1 then try this foreach($tweetsArr[0] as $tweet) {